# showing extra color boxes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm new in tradingview pinescript code. So, some problems I don't know how to fix.
I removed all the input.*() operator from the script to remove the Input tab in the Settings (Line 22 to 38).
When I did that, there are extra 2 color box showing -> Color 1, Color 2 [Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/HkmnkLmD/color0.jpg).

How do I remove these Color boxes including Color 0 without Input tab like this -> [Edited above Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/nrj5hswh/color-1-2.jpg).

Here is the whole script

```html
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © cryptoweeknd

//@version=5
indicator("ADR", overlay=true)

//ADR side of script below

text_ADR1_high = 'ADR Upper'
text_ADR2_high = 'ADR Upper'

text_ADR1_low = 'ADR Lower'
text_ADR2_low = 'ADR Lower'

lime = #00FF00 //ADR2 Low
limes = #00FF00 //ADR1 Low
red = #FF4000 //ADR1 High
reds = #FF4000 //ADR2 High

//***Start of Inputs

labels_enabled = true

color_ADR1_high = red
color_ADR2_high = reds

color_ADR1_low = lime
color_ADR2_low = limes

adrUppercolorfill = red
adrlowercolorfill = lime
   
//***End of Inputs

//***Start of local functions definiton***

adr_1 = 10
adr_2 = 5

draw_line(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2, _xloc, _extend, _color, _style, _width) =>
    dline = line.new(x1=_x1, y1=_y1, x2=_x2, y2=_y2, xloc=_xloc, extend=_extend, color=_color, style=_style, width=_width)
    line.delete(dline[1])
    
draw_label(_x, _y, _text, _xloc, _yloc, _color, _style, _textcolor, _size, _textalign, _tooltip) =>
    dlabel = label.new(x=_x, y=_y, text=_text, xloc=_xloc, yloc=_yloc, color=_color, style=_style, textcolor=_textcolor, size=_size, textalign=_textalign, tooltip=_tooltip)
    label.delete(dlabel[1])

//If security is futures - replace the ticker with continuous contract
tickerid_func() =>
    tickerid = syminfo.tickerid
    if syminfo.type == 'futures'
        tickerid := syminfo.root + '1!'

//Function to calculate ADR levels
//Parameters:
//  * lengthInput - ADR period
//  * hi_low - true-->High, else-->Low 
adr_func(lengthInput,hi_low) =>
    float result = 0
    float adr = 0
    open_ = request.security(tickerid_func(), "D", open, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    adr_High = request.security(tickerid_func(), "D", ta.sma(high[1], lengthInput), barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    adr_Low = request.security(tickerid_func(), "D", ta.sma(low[1], lengthInput), barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    adr := (adr_High - adr_Low)
    
    if hi_low//High
        result := adr/2 + open_
    else    //Low
        result := open_ - adr/2    

//Workaround to disable color management on the standard tab Style for plots
//Custom inputs for colors should be used instead
transp_func() =>
    transp_0 = 0

//***End of local functions definiton***

//***Start of getting data

start_time = request.security(tickerid_func(), "D", time_close[1],barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)
open__ = request.security(tickerid_func(), "D", open, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

start_time1 = request.security(tickerid_func(), "W", time_close[1],barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)

adr1_high = adr_func(adr_1,true)
adr1_low = adr_func(adr_1,false)
adr2_high = adr_func(adr_2,true)
adr2_low = adr_func(adr_2,false)

//***End of getting data

float _adr1_high = na
float _adr1_low = na
float _adr2_high = na
float _adr2_low = na
float _open = na

//*********************

//***Start of plotting*

//Decide if we can show the chart:
//Daily levels should be visible on intraday chart only

var show_chart = false

if timeframe.isintraday
    show_chart := true
    
//Plot all days
if show_chart
    _adr1_high := adr1_high
    _adr1_low  := adr1_low
    _adr2_high := adr2_high
    _adr2_low  := adr2_low
    _open      := open__

ADR1_high = plot(_adr1_high, title=text_ADR1_high, color=ta.change(_adr1_high) ? na : color_ADR1_high, linewidth=1)
ADR2_high = plot(_adr2_high, title=text_ADR2_high, color=ta.change(_adr2_high) ? na : color_ADR2_high, linewidth=1)
ADR1_low = plot(_adr1_low, title=text_ADR1_low, color=ta.change(_adr1_low) ? na : color_ADR1_low, linewidth=1)
ADR2_low = plot(_adr2_low, title=text_ADR2_low, color=ta.change(_adr2_low) ? na : color_ADR2_low, linewidth=1)
fill(plot1 = ADR1_high, plot2 = ADR2_high, color = ta.change(_adr1_high) ? na : color.new(adrUppercolorfill, 80))
fill(plot1 = ADR1_low, plot2 = ADR2_low, color = ta.change(_adr1_low) ? na : color.new(adrlowercolorfill, 80))

//***Start of Labels***

label_ADR1_high = ''
label_ADR2_high = ''

label_ADR1_low = ''
label_ADR2_low = ''

if labels_enabled == true
    label_ADR1_high := str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(adr1_high))
    label_ADR2_high := str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(adr2_high))
    
    label_ADR1_low  := str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(adr1_low))
    label_ADR2_low  := str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(adr2_low))
        
string_ADR1_high = ' (' + label_ADR1_high + ')'
string_ADR2_high = ' (' + label_ADR2_high + ')'

string_ADR1_low = ' (' + label_ADR1_low + ')'
string_ADR2_low = ' (' + label_ADR2_low + ')'

//Labels
if show_chart and labels_enabled == true
    draw_label(bar_index + 1, adr1_high, text_ADR1_high + string_ADR1_high, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.new(color.white, 100), label.style_label_left, color.new(color_ADR1_high,transp_func()), size.normal, text.align_left, '') 
    draw_label(bar_index + 1, adr2_high, text_ADR2_high + string_ADR2_high, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.new(color.white, 100), label.style_label_left, color.new(color_ADR2_high,transp_func()), size.normal, text.align_left, '')
  
    draw_label(bar_index + 1, adr1_low,  text_ADR1_low + string_ADR1_low, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.new(color.white, 100), label.style_label_left, color.new(color_ADR1_low,transp_func()), size.normal, text.align_left, '')   
    draw_label(bar_index + 1, adr2_low,  text_ADR2_low + string_ADR2_low, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color.new(color.white, 100), label.style_label_left, color.new(color_ADR2_low,transp_func()), size.normal, text.align_left, '')  

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Does adding `editable=false` to your `plot()` functions solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you @vitruvius. When I add editable=false I unable to change line [color](https://i.postimg.cc/jj2ZXn3T/f.jpg). We need to change line color like [this](https://postlmg.cc/kRCwj5m0)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to get rid of all color options including Color 0, Color 1 and Color 2. Is what you want is just one color per each plot?

Comment: I want to remove Color 1 and Color 2 boxes without [input tab](https://i.postimg.cc/yxkPWbpq/input.jpg)  like [this](https://postlmg.cc/kRCwj5m0). I can't remove ta.change() function, because it will merg lines with previous [days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347237/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed when I remove `Labels` scripts (line 125 to 152)

Answer (score 0):

What is **style tab** anyway? It **is completely controlled by tradingview**. It contains all the styling options it could automatically find in your script. So I think you should not care about it at all, but it is only my personal opinion. Do you want to really customize and style your script? Then use inputs, that you can group however you want.
Back to your question, why is it the way it is?
 Because you have 3 color options in your plot due to the ternary operator you use for coloring: `color=ta.change(_adr1_high) ? na : color_ADR1_high`
in the style tab then: `color0` if your condition is false, `color1` if your condition is true. I'm not sure what `color2` stands for but you may find it out yourself.
So as for me, the best solution is to use inputs instead of trying to manipulate the auto color options, since that tab is a kind of a black box concerning the options that are offered to you thus having only little control over it.